# Which Comes First: Standardization or Transformation?

Tags: data-transformation, normalization, standardization, scales

I have a data frame that contains a few variables where the skew is larger than 1. Also most of the variables have vastly different scales. I am looking to scale the data using R's scale() function (this function takes the number, subtracts the mean and divides by the standard deviation). As well, I would like to get rid of the non-normality.

Should I scale my data first and than use a transformation (log, sqrt etc..) or should I do the vice versa?

I can post data, but I am looking for an intuitive answer rather than a solution to a specific problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Scaling is a simple example of a transformation.  In this sense your question is "what should come first--a simple (scaling) transformation or a more general transformation."  That's hard to answer because there's really nothing to say: carry out any sequence of transformations you need however you see fit.

Comment: Why are you wanting to transform to normality?

Comment: Because most models assume normal distribution of my variables